# Siteminder 403 - possible causes

Tags: authentication, http-get, siteminder

Im pretty new to webservice etc and I need figure out what is causing a http 403 response code.

I am hitting a service that was recently secured using siteminder, what I need to find out is what siteminder expects when receiving a http get request. Is there anyway I can find this out I assume that it is authenticating correctly due to the 403.

Im thinking that the request maybe missing some headers or indeed cookies I'm just finding it hard figuring out what is needed and would be great if I can get some guidance into how to at least find out what is expected.

I can hit the service fine through the browser.

T.I.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn on tracing on the web agent, check the log and see what headers are being sent, and if the 403 is coming from SiteMinder or your web service